# Proving a set is open.

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

> Let $E,||\cdot||$ be a finite dimensional normed space over $\mathbb R$.
>
> Let $U$ be an open subset of $E$ and $a\in U$
>
> Let $A=\{x\in E \;|\; \forall t\in [0,1], (1-t)a+tx\in U\}$
>
> Prove that $A$ is open.

Intuitively, $A$ is the set of points $x$ such that the line segment from $a$ to $x$ lies inside $U$.

Pick some $x\in A$. One needs to find some $r>0$ such that the open ball centered at $x$ with radius $r$ is a subset of $A$. Since $a\in U$ and $x\in U$, there are some $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $B(r_1,a)\subset U$ and  $B(r_2,a)\subset U$. Setting $r:=\min(r_1,r_2)$ seems plausible, but I can't prove that it fits the bill.

I tried contradiction as well, to no avail. This yields the existence of $x_n$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $x_n \notin A$. That seems impossible, but I can't reach any contradiction.

Comment: "One needs to find some r>0 such that the open ball centered at x with radius r is a subset of U." Incorrect. That would show that U is open, not A.

Comment: @avid19 You're right, typo fixed.

Comment: Also, your "contradiction" wouldn't show that A is open. It would simply show that A is not closed.

Comment: @avid19 I disagree. Supposing that $A$ is not open, there is some $x$, such that $\forall r >0$, there is some $y\in B(x,r)\setminus A$. With the right $r$, you can build the sequence $x_n$ I referred to.

Comment: What is your $x_n$ and how would it show A is open?

Comment: @avid19 I'm attempting to write up what is known as a proof by contradiction.

Comment: I know what a proof by contradiction is.

Comment: @avid19 Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: @avid19: if $A$ is not open, then there is some $x \in A$ such that every neighborhood of $x$ contains some point $x_n \not\in A$. I.e. $\{x_n\} \in A^c$ and $x_n \to x$.

Comment: I must have misread it then. Yes, that would work. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Open_set definition and http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Norm#Norms_may_define_a_metric_space

Comment: setting $r:=\min(r_1,r_2)$ would not generally work as should be easily seen from the picture that I posted with my answer. Intuitively the minimum of the radii should be taken over all points on the line segment between $a$ and $x$, which could be made more precise using compactness of the line segment and the notion of [Lebesgue number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma): vive le francais!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in A$ then $x\in U$: Just take $t=1$ in the definition of $A$.

Fix $x\in A$ and let $X$ denote the closed line segment from $a$ to $x$. As you noted, $X\subset U$.
Since $U$ is open, for each $y \in X$ there is $\varepsilon_y>0$ such that 
$B(\varepsilon_y,y)\subseteq U$.
Since $X$ is compact there is $\lambda_x>0$ such that $B(\lambda_x,y)\subseteq U$ for all $y \in X$.
(Use the [Lebesgue number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) for the relative open cover of $X$ by the $B(\varepsilon_y,y)$, $y\in X$.
Formally if $\delta$ is the Lebesgue number then we may pick $\lambda_x<\delta/2$.
Then, for any $y\in X$ we have $\mathrm{diam}\, B(\lambda_x,y)<\delta$, hence
$B(\lambda_x,y)\subseteq B(\varepsilon_v,v)\subseteq U$ for some $v\in X$.)
Now take any $z$ in $B(\lambda_x,x)$. Clearly the line segment $Z$ from $a$ to $z$ lies in $B(\lambda_x,X):=\cup\{B(\lambda_x,y):y \in X)\} \subseteq U$.
It follows that $z\in A$, hence $B(\lambda_x,x) \subseteq A$.
This completes the proof that $A$ is open.

[image]